# How to show expanded scroll bars in a UWP DataGrid

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP application that uses DataGrid controls.

When my application runs, the vertical scroll bars are visible only as a thin line, until you mouse over it, and then it turns into a regular scroll bar.

My users do not like this. They want it to show up as a regular scroll bar permanently. Is this possible?

I already have VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" in the DataGrid element, so that's not the issue.

Frank

Comment: My app is primarily used on touch screen computers where this is not an issue, but a portion of my user base is using desktop PCs with a mouse, and they are the ones having the problem.

Comment: A quick solution is to enable the system settings. Go to **Settings**-> **Accessibiity** -> **Visual effects**, then enable the **Always show scrollbars** option.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will solve the problem for us!